# Can you use substitution, then by parts when integrating?

Tags: calculus

How do you integrate $2x/(2x-1)^2$ ?

I'm told to use the substitution $u=2x-1$

I get to 0.5 X "integral of" (u+1)/u^2 and then I do it by parts...
This leads me to a solution with x's but no logs which is what wolfram alpha tells me is correct...

What have I missed? Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: $\frac{u+1}{u^2} = \frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{u^2}$

Comment: What solution are you getting? Combining substitution and integration by parts seems a perfectly legitimate way to solve this problem. Just remember to "un-substitute" the $x$ back in at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=2x-1$; $dx=\frac{1}{2}\,du$. The integral is:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{u+1}{u^2}\, du=\frac{1}{2}\int\left(\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{u^2}\right)du$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int\frac{1}{u}\,du+\int\frac{1}{u^2}\,du\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln|u|-\frac{1}{u}\right)+C$$

You can do it by parts, but it's not worth it. The integral $\int\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}dx$, where $P(x),Q(x)$ are polynomials, can always be computed similarly (you may need to apply the "Partial Fractions" method).

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's okay to combine substitution and integration by parts. Since in essence, your question is "*Why do I get a different solution than Wolframalpha?*", I'll answer that.

In short, if your answer doesn't involve logarithms, it is (most likely) wrong. Since I can't comment on your try (as you didn't provide it), I'll show how I would do it with substitution and integration by parts.

Let $u=2x-1$ and use substition:

$$\int \frac{2x}{(2x-1)^2} dx=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{u+1}{u^2} du$$

Let $f(u)=u+1, g'(u)=u^{-2}$ and use integration by parts:

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2}\int f(u)g'(u) du&= \frac{1}{2}\left((f(u)g(u) - \int f'(u) g(u)du\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left( (u+1)\frac{1}{-u}-\int -\frac{1}{u} \cdot 1 du\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{u+1}{u}+\ln |u|\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{u}+\ln|u|\right)-0.5\end{align}$$

So including the constant and absorbing $-0.5$ into it, we get

$$ \frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{u}+\ln|u|\right)+C$$

You can now resubstitute $u=2x-1$.

**Notes:** Of course you can switch $f$ and $g$ above. If you used it as above, this probably helps to find your mistake. If not, please provide your computation. Also, this might not be the most elegant or most straightforward way to find that integral, see the answer by user236182.